# Recursive Persistence of a number

Tags: c

I am trying to find the persistence of a number. When you multiply the digits of a number together, eventually you will arrive at a single digit number. Persistence is the number of cycles that takes. I am trying to find that using a recursive Function. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int persistence(int x);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int x, per = 0, t;
  char c;
  while((c = getchar())!= EOF)
    {
      printf("Enter a number:\n");
      scanf("%d", &x);
      while(x>10)
        {
           t = persistence(x);
           printf("\n%d", persistence(t));
           per++;
         }
      printf("\n%d\n\n", per);

    }
  return 0;
}

int persistence(int x)
{
  if(x<10)
    {
      return x;
    }
  else
    {

      return (x%10 * persistence(x/10));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you're returning the number itself (rather than 1) when the number is less than 10.  That's simply wrong, according to your problem statement.

Comment: By your own definition, the persistence of number < 10 is 1. So `if(x<10) return 1; else { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

The function `persistence` itself should return the value of the multiplicative persistence.

It can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t persistence( unsigned int x )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;

    if ( ! ( x < Base ) )
    {
        unsigned int n = 1;
        do { n *= x % Base; } while ( x /= Base );
        return 1 + persistence( n );
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }       
}

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int x = 39;

    printf( "persistence( %u ) = %zu\n", x, persistence( x ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
persistence( 39 ) = 3
```